# why the result of sizeof for tertiary operating is 4？

Tags: c, sizeof

who can help explain the program result:

```
  int main()
    {
    char a=1;
    short b=1;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof((b==a)?a:b));
    printf("%d %d", sizeof(a), sizeof(b));

    return 0;
    }
```

print out is

```
4
1 2
```

Comment: I'm not a C person, but I'm guessing that `a` is being cast to an integer because of the `%d` formatting mask in your call to `printf`.  Print it as a character, and maybe this won't happen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nor quite.  The value and type of `(b==a)?a:b)` are determined before `sizeof` and all that is determined before the `printf()` call and the application of `"%d"`.

Comment: @chux I should have added "or something like that" to my comment to cover my bases :-)

Answer (score 4):

From C Standard#6.5.3.4p2 *[emphasis mine]*

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

In the expression:

```
sizeof((b==a)?a:b)
```

the `char` and `short` will be converted to `int` due to default type promotion<sup>1)</sup> and the whole expression evaluated to `int` type. Hence, you are getting the output as `4`.

Also, the type of the result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. You should use `%zu` format specifier instead of `%d`.

---

1) [Default Type Promotions and Conversions](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html)

Answer (score 1):

When an integer value whose type has rank lower than that of `int` (such as `char` or `short`) is used in an expression, it is automatically **promoted** to type `int`.

In the case of the expression `(b==a)?a:b`, both possible values are promoted to type `int`, so the expression as a whole has type `int`.  Therefore the `sizeof` operator is evaluating to the size of an `int`, which on your machine is 4.

Note also that the expression passed to `sizeof` is **not** evaluated at runtime.  It is only parsed by the compiler to determine its type.  The only time the operand of `sizeof` is evaluated at runtime is if the operand is a variable length array.